# How to disable site specific search in chrome omnibox

Tags: macos, google-chrome, search, github, omnibox

Every time I start typing a search string into the Chrome omnibox which starts with "github", Chrome turns it into a site-specific search (see attached GIF).

This only seems to happen for GitHub. I don't think this is due to an extension because it even happens in incognito windows. This effectively makes it impossible to search for anything starting with the word "github".

**How can I disable this behavior?**

[image]

Comment: Have you uninstalled or disabled the add-on to verify it is without a shadow of doubt not cause by an add-on?  This does not happen to me.

Comment: I disabled all extensions ([screenshot](http://s27.postimg.org/8xpath2j7/Screen_Shot_2016_01_20_at_1_04_32_PM.png)) then restarted Chrome. The undesirable behavior still happens. "About Google Chrome" shows "Version 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chrome's Settings, Search, Manage search engines under your entry for github change the middle field (Keyword) to something that won't so readily capture github search.

E.g. change *github* to *github.com* or *search_github*.

The keyword field is used for the trigger to invoke the particular search engine.

Comment: This is how to disable the annoying Press tab to send commands to Secure Shell App feature when you want to search google for an ssh related question

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33590538/1529675

This behavior can be caused by a "Custom Search Engine" in Chrome preferences. Go in to Settings, Search, then Manage search engines, then scroll down to find and remove Github (or the offending specific site).

Answer (score 1):

To not search github but send the search terms to your default search engine for just that search type Shift-Backspace after you see the "Search GitHub:" and continue typing.